# link is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i am using the jquery for developing my system.
for particular functionality i am sending link through json data to have link for each row 
of jqgrid table.
as

```
"<a href='#' class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil' onclick='EditClick(\"" + {MYPRIMARY KEY}+ "\");return false;'>Edit</a>"
```

in javasript i have function as

```
function EditClick(param) 
{          
    $('#mainDiv').load('/contoller/action/' + param, function() {
    });
    return false;
}
```

here action returns the view().

in this EditClick function i am loading another page in my main div.

This runs on IE7,firefox smoothly,but using it on IE8 sometimes its works sometimes not.
i mean sometime required page loads in main div sometimes not.
i realy dont understand the problem.
please guide me through this.
thank you.

Comment: What are the conditions under which IE8 fails to load? Try using Fiddler to see what the response to the request is; I'm guessing the action returns an error code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a few problems working with jgGrid events a row.
What I did was to add a custom button:

```
jQuery("myGrid").navGrid('#myPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {})
    .navButtonAdd('#myPager', { caption: "Do something", buttonicon: "ui-icon-note", 
        onClickButton: function() { var rowid = jQuery("myGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'); 
            if ((rowid == null) || (rowid == 0)) { 
                alert("Select a row before!"); } 
            else { 
                EditClick(rowid); 
                } 
                }, position: "last" })
```

As you can see the function EditClick is triggered only if you've selected one row in the grid. rowid should be your primary key.

Hope it helps.

Comment: actualy i am sending my primary key with link.and no need to select row ,user can directly click on that pencil icon to edit that particular row (edit page is loaded after edit click).

Comment: is the pencil icon external to the jqGrid?